# Checking if AssetImage asset path exist

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-assetimage, flutter-material

How do I load AssetImage or check if it exists? The data is coming from the api, so I cannot list all the file paths as constants.

As an example path maybe be 'assets/images/${card.imageType}.png' where card.inageType is a variable.

```dart
...
child: Image(
       height: 60.0,
       image: Utils.getImage('assets/images/card-${card.category}.png'),
       ),
...
```

For my getImage function, I tried  2 kinds but not working

**Method 1**: Using File: The existsSync method is always false. Keep in mind the await async cannot work as the Image widget is expecting not a Future

```dart
static dynamic getImage(path) {
    File f = File(path);
    return f.existsSync()
        ? FileImage(f)
        : const AssetImage('assets/images/default.png');
  }
}
```

**Method 2**: Using try catch: The exceptions is not being caught

```dart
  static AssetImage getImage(path) {
    AssetImage image;

    try {
      image = AssetImage(path);
    } catch (e) {
      image = const AssetImage('assets/images/default.png');
    }

    return image;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a file exists asynchronously with this code:

```
import 'dart:io';
File("path/to/file").exists()
```

or checking it synchronously:

```
import 'dart:io';
File("path/to/file").existsSync()
```

**Update:**

isPathExists() function is called from initState.

AssetBundle is used for to obtain asset inside asset folder. You can insert anything to *menubanner.png* if it exists, the image will be assigned to variable and if it does not, an exception throws.

```
  late Image image;
  isPathExists() async {
    try {
      var assetbundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
      ByteData res = await assetbundle.load('assets/images/menubanner.png');
      var list = Uint8List.sublistView(res);
      setState(() {
        image = Image.memory(list);
      });
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Read the question again, "File f = File(path); line, I tried that and it always return false and async doesn't work as the Image doesn't expect Future

Comment: @Tremmillicious sorry for the inconvenience. I updated the answer. Can you check if that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to check if an asset exists:

```
// example: 'assets/check_green.png' 
Future<bool> checkIfAssetExists(String fullAssetPath) async {
  final Uint8List encoded = Utf8Codec()
      .encoder
      .convert(Uri(path: Uri.encodeFull(fullAssetPath)).path);
  // returns null if an asset is not found
  final ByteData? asset = await ServicesBinding.instance!.defaultBinaryMessenger
      .send('flutter/assets', encoded.buffer.asByteData());
  return asset != null;
}
```

You can run this in your `initState` and then use `AssetImage` confidently.

As for the exception not being caught, it probably means than an `Error` was throw which is different from `Exception`s

Answer (score 0):

For this, I created an async method to check if the file exists, and load a default value if the file doesn't exists, and in my UI, I use a future builder.. Something like.

```
  static Future<ImageProvider<Object>> loadImage(
  BuildContext context, String imagePath) async {
try {
  final bundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
  await bundle.load(imagePath);
  return AssetImage(imagePath);
} catch (e) {
  return const AssetImage("assets/no_image_placeholder.png");
}}
```

And then in the UI,

```
  SizedBox(
          height: 100.0,
          width: 160.0,
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: ProductFallbackErrorImage.loadImage(context,
                "assets/product_images/${productName.toLowerCase()}.jpg"),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 160.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: snapshot.data as ImageProvider<Object>,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                'snapshot has error with value ${snapshot.error.toString()}'
                    .log();
                return Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 160.0,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/no_image_placeholder.png"),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
```

The error block will never be executed, since we are handling the level of the catch block, so i guess that can be removed.

Answer (score -1):

You can not use Asset Image for images fetched from Network.

Once you get response from your api. Store the url of the image in a String variable. Usually images from API are stored in a web service.

When you have the url of the image just use NetworkImage widget, example:

```
SizedBox(
     width: 75,
     height: 75,
     child: userImgUrl.isEmpty
     ? const CircleAvatar(
     child: Text('Avatar'))
     : CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                             userImgUrl),
                             backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),)
```

Think userImgUrl is the String that holds the url for the image that can be found on the internet. If image is empty just show a text inside circle avatar. If image is available from API, then show the image inside **NetworkImage()**

Comment: read the question again. The images are in Assets, only the path is assembled from the API

Comment: Sorry your question was not clear to me.